# To remove characters in the beginnings of lines

Tags: commands, comment, rectangle

To add `//` in the beginnings of multiple lines I can use either `string-insert-rectangle` or `string-rectangle` (`C-x r t`).

But how is it possible to *remove* these characters instead?

This question is not just about `//`. It may be any other character or characters. For example, I might want to change

```
011aa
012bb
013cc
```

to

```
1aa
2bb
3cc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete-rectangle`; default binding is `C-x r d`. See also `comment-dwim`, bound to `M-;` by default, if you are adding and removing comments. The whole `C-x r` map is useful, don’t forget that you can type any prefix followed by `C-h` to get a list of keybindings with that prefix.

Comment: `comment-dwim` is bound to `M-;` on emacs 28.1.

Comment: Oops, typo. Thanks for letting me know.